# Winform Datagridview cellclick error - Index was out of range

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I've got a simple data grid that lists a bunch of records from a SQLSERVER table. The data grid populates without any issues. I want to click on a row and load the corresponding data into text boxes that I have created next to it. So far so simple.

Here is my code for the cellclick event

```
    private void dataGridVieworderitems_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            //try
            //{
                //if (dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows.Count > 0) // make sure user select at least 1 row 
                {
                    string jobId = dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
                    string standpack = dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
                    string description = dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
                    string price = dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;
                    string itemType = dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;
                    string notes = dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value + string.Empty;

                    labelidvalue.Text = jobId;
                    labelstandpackvalue.Text = standpack;
                    labeldescriptionvalue.Text = description;
                    textBoxprice.Text = price;
                    labeltypevalue.Text = itemType;
                    textBoxnotes.Text = notes;
                }
            //}
            //catch (Exception)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("something went wrong!");
            //}
        }
    }
```

I have deliberately commented out the If statement and try catch block to generate the error.. 
I get the following error..

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233086
>   Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection. Parameter name: index   ParamName=index ....
>   ...

It's WINFORM and c#.. The datagrid view has the data.. yet it says index is out of range. can some one point me in the right direction please?

This is how I Populate my grid

```
    public DataTable GetStaffCurrentOrderItems()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtstaffcurrentorderlist = new DataTable();

            string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nav"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [ID],standpack as [Item], item_description as [Description], '$'+convert(varchar(5),price) as Price,item_type as [Item Type],notes as [Notes] from tbl_staff_orders_items", con))
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dtstaffcurrentorderlist.Load(reader);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return dtstaffcurrentorderlist;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Harry how many rows do you have in your datagrid?

Comment: The data set returns about 25 rows and it is NEVER empty.. Thank you

Comment: And as a separate question, what do you need  '+ string.Empty' for?

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your help. No matter what I did.. I couldn't get it to work. So I simply started from scratch doing the same thing and it works fine now. !!!

Answer (score 3):

Make a check within your `cellClick` event handler for handling the nulls like this

```
if (dataGridVieworderitems.CurrentCell == null ||
    dataGridVieworderitems.CurrentCell.Value == null ||
    e.RowIndex == -1) return;
```

This will sort out your problem as it checks for all the possible nulls while clicking the cell of `GridView`. An else part will get you the data if there is anything except null.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this will not sort the problem out, as it's SelectedRows collection, that is empty, not the Cells

Comment: Thanks.. I know how to avoid getting an error.. but that leaves me with nothing that works..why am I hitting the issue is my questions..

Answer (score 2):

```
Index was out of range
```

This means index not found on your datagrid cell.

Kindly check the rows of you datagrid if `index exists` same with the `column` too.

Comment: Thanks Reds, I understand the issue.. the questions is, when the data is clearly available, when does the index not exist? I'm hoping someone will help me understand this.

Comment: for example.. your are pointing like this "string price = dataGridVieworderitems.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;". but your datagrid cell does contain only two columns.. it will returns an error "Index was out of range". Index starts with 0 and so on...

Comment: thanks Reds.. I'm still trying to work through this and haven't been able to resolve this.. I can guarantee that there is a minimum of 20 rows of data with 5 columns. They all show in the grid.. just the events that I'm trying to trigger are complaining about it!

Comment: Can you show your sample data here. and error returns of your code.

Comment: sample data 'code'
1 03100 Local Rump VP $8.25 Ordinary 
2 03108 Steer Chuck Roll VP $7.75 Ordinary 
3 03154 Steer Clod IW  $7.50 Ordinary FROZEN ONLY
4 03204 Steer Point End   $6.50 Ordinary FROZEN ONLY

Comment: http://tinypic.com/m/jju58m/3
Error message..

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: it returns out of range coz maybe your datagird doesn't have a content yet.

Comment: This is what I don't understand.. how can datagrid not have content when I can clearly see the content and all my data on run time?

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**
Ha, got the exact problem source:
The SelectionMode property must be set to **FullRowSelect** for the SelectedRows property to be populated with selected rows.

Otherwise you can use the following options:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string jobId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        }
```

or

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex];
            string jobId = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Jury, have tried selectionchanged event, but cannot use RowIndex as eventargs does not have definition for RowIndex.. I'm confused cause the same thing works fine on another project.. yet not on this one!

Comment: RowIndex is in CellClick event. SelectionChanged event has SelectedRows collection

Comment: Still no luck with this unfortunately. I've tried all combinations that I could think of and I'm starting to pull my hair out.. it's so simple.. yet seems so out of reach!